# tense in answering a question about prose or poetry

Tags: present-tense, subject-verb-agreement, past-simple, historical-present

Can anyone please tell me if I am asked questions in **present tense** from a prose and poem, should I give answers in **present tense** or in **past tense**?

Here is the poem **'The Owl'** by Edward Thomas from which A question was asked in my exam:

> And salted was my food, and my repose,
>   Salted and sobered, too, by the bird’s voice
>   Speaking for all who lay under the stars,
>   Soldiers and poor, unable to rejoice.

Here is the question that was asked in the exam:

- We generally add salt to our food to improve its taste. So, what **does** the poet mean when he **says** 'salted was my food'? Why **does** he feel that way?

> **Answer**: Salt **improves** the taste of food. But here the poet **uses** the word 'salted' in the sense of 'oversalted'. His food **appeared** to be tasteless to him.
>
> It **is** the thought of the miseries of the helpless poor people and the soldiers serving at the front which **makes** him feel that way. Unlike him, these people **suffers** the biting cold of the North wind, without food and shelter.

I gave the answer written above. My question is should I answer in present tense as the question is in **present tense** or in **past tense**. As the poem was written in the past and everything happened in the past, does the present sound appropriate there?

Comment: You have a number disagreement there, BTW.  It should be *these people **suffer***.

Comment: **prose** is uncountable, so we'd say "a piece of prose" or "a prose work".

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a strict rule for a situation like this. But because the question is written in present tense, it makes sense to respond with an answer that is also present tense. And if the *poem* were written in *past* tense, I would try to preserve that as well. So if I were to paraphrase the poem in my analysis, I would try to paraphrase the actions that take place in the poem in past (or past perfect) tense.

Generally, you don't want to change tenses unless there's a real reason to do so, and I don't see a good reason to depart from the voice the instructor has decided to use. The present tense is often employed to increase the immediacy of dialogue -- almost as if you were having a discussion with your instructor over a cup of coffee. The present tense helps remind us that we're not talking about some stodgy, ancient poem about people long dead; rather, we're having a vibrant discussion about writing that is still relevant today.

Answer (score 1):

It is conventional to speak of what a text **says** rather than what it **said** when we are referring to it as part of the present moment:

> I'm holding in my hand a letter from my cousin in Antarctica.
>   --That's exciting. What **does** it **say**?

or when we are referring to a literary work, and then we speak of the work as though the author's voice were present in it:

> The poet **says** that his "repose" was "salted ... by the bird's voice".

We use the past tense of texts normally when placing them in the context of some past action or event:

> When I got home that night several weeks ago, there was a note on the fridge.
>   -- And what **did** the note **say**?